# PHP не создает папку в Centos

Tags: php, centos

Выдает ошибку:

> Message: mkdir(): Permission denied
> Filename: helpers/utilities_helper.php
> Line Number: 68
>
> Severity: Warning Message: chmod(): No
> such file or directory Filename:
> helpers/utilities_helper.php Line
> Number: 71

```
<?
mkdir($pathToFile, 0775, true);
chmod( $pathToFile, 0775);
?>
```

Как быть? Может через terminal выставить нужные права на публичную дирректорию?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, а мы должны догадаться о содержимом переменной $pathToFile? 

И заодно о текущем id, владельцах и правах на все катологи в пути.

Comment: От корня сайта путь к создаваемой дирректории:
     public/loaded/photousers/2014/07/11/13/02

Права на папку public: rwxr-xr-x
Владелец: root [0]
Пользователь: root [0]

Comment: А скрипт от кого исполняется? Тоже от рута?

Comment: А как определить? узнать права на этот файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Oleg Ponomarchuk](/users/18030/oleg-ponomarchuk), как всегда.

Зайти на сервер и посмотреть (команда ls -l).

Или Вас интересует от кого (т.е. uid) скрипт работает? Это команда `id` покажет. Выполните ее в скрипте и положите ее вывод куда-нибудь.

Вообще, Вы все так описываете, что постоянно приходится просто гадать, что именно Вы делаете.

Скрипт этот Вы руками запускате или когда с сервером через браузер какой-нибудь общаетесь его сервер запускает?

На будущее -- побольше надо в вопросе информации о ситуации давать.